# Group data by probability of column value occurring in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data that has the following structure:

```
  month         Responder       Status  Frequency
  2020-02-01    A                 TRUE  1
  2020-03-01    B                FALSE  1
  2020-03-01    B                 TRUE  2
  2020-03-01    C                FALSE  1
  2020-03-01    C                 TRUE  1
  2020-03-01    D                FALSE  1
  2020-03-01    E                FALSE  1
  2020-03-01    F                FALSE  2
  2020-03-01    G                FALSE  1
  2020-03-01    G                 TRUE  2
  2020-03-01    H                 TRUE  1
```

I now want to create a data frame showing the probability of each responder's status being FALSE, grouped by the month. The output should therefore look like this, where n is the number of times the Responder is listed for the month:

```
  month         Responder         n    prob_false
  2020-02-01    A                 1    0
  2020-03-01    B                 2    0.333
  2020-03-01    C                 2    0.5
  2020-03-01    D                 1    1
  2020-03-01    E                 1    1
  2020-03-01    F                 1    1
  2020-03-01    G                 2    0.333
  2020-03-01    H                 1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and based on @akrun's very useful comment:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Responder, month) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), prob_false = sum(Frequency[!Status])/sum(Frequency))

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   Responder [8]
  Responder month          n prob_false
  <chr>     <chr>      <int>      <dbl>
1 A         2020-02-01     1      0    
2 B         2020-03-01     2      0.333
3 C         2020-03-01     2      0.5  
4 D         2020-03-01     1      1    
5 E         2020-03-01     1      1    
6 F         2020-03-01     1      1    
7 G         2020-03-01     2      0.333
8 H         2020-03-01     1      0
```

Comment: I think you need `summarise` `df1 %>% group_by(Responder, month) %>% summarise(n = n(), prob_false = sum(Frequency[!Status])/sum(Frequency))`